# Trying to create a lookup field but unable to find the source field

Tags: list, column, lookup-column

I created 2 lists (A and B).

```
A
Field1
field2
Field3

B
Field4
Field5
Field6
```

On A I have a lookup field *Field2* which is based on the *Field4* of B.
It works fine.

I would like to make a lookup in *Field3* with data of the *Field6* of B

In the scroll list, *Field6* doesn't appear...

*Field6* is a normal field in B.

Anybody could help me please?

Comment: What is the field type of `Field6` ?

Answer (score 0):

List of SP Column types available for lookup

[image: SP Columns availabe for LookUp]

Below list of column types are not available for look up

[image: SP Columns not availabe for LookUp]

Source : [SharePoint: Not all column types can be used in Calculated or Lookup columns (plus a trick to add back four of them!)](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2012/01/sharepoint-not-all-column-types-can-be.html)